# Calculate Sum of Contract Revenue between Two Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two sheets in an Excel workbook. The first is a list of contracts for workers A, B, and C and the contracted revenue rate per day.

[image]

The next sheet is a reporting table that calculates the total revenue for each of A, B, C between two dates.

[image]

What formula should I have in D3 to properly query the table of contracts, get all of A's contracts, and sum A's revenues from all its contracts only between the days in the period?

**EDIT: As a related follow-on question. How would I calculate the number of days under contract in each time period?**

Answer (score 2):

iterate the days with `ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,L$2+1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,M$2))`

And use SUMIFS() to return the rate if the day is between the start and end and the workers match:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($G$3:$G$6,$E$3:$E$6,"<="&ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,L$2+1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,M$2)),$F$3:$F$6,">="&ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,L$2+1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,M$2)),$A$3:$A$6,$J3))
```

[image]

---

If one has Office 365 Insider version of Excel, or Microsoft finally released it, the `ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,L$2+1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,M$2))` can be replaces with `SEQUENCE(M$2-L$2,,L$2+1)`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($G$3:$G$6,$E$3:$E$6,"<="&SEQUENCE(M$2-L$2,,L$2+1),$F$3:$F$6,">="&SEQUENCE(M$2-L$2,,L$2+1),$A$3:$A$6,$J3))
```

Comment: Could you explain `INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,L$2+1)`? First, `$ZZ:$ZZ` and the `+1`.

Comment: This calculation also includes both the start date and end date of the contracts, i.e. Start Date of 10/25/19 and End Date of 11/25/19 is (11/25/19-10/25/19 + 1) days long. How would I not include either the start or end date as a day under the contract (so there is no + 1)?

Comment: it sets a range from the end date of the last period +1 to the end date of the current period.  The ROW then returns a range of number between those dates.  I choose Column ZZ just because most likely there is no data in those columns that may cause unneeded calculations.  The column is not important.  It could be `$A:$A` or any column.  The `+1` adds a day to the last date of the last period.

Comment: Thanks, see follow-on question regarding how to calculate number of days under contract.